# Why does assigning a new value to an array fail in PHP?

Tags: php

Consider:

```
array (size=1)
  0 =>
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string '15268459735 Farming and Projects XXXXX' (length=38)
      'region' => string '2' (length=1)
      'entitynumber' => string '2012/002086/24' (length=14)
      'ownership' => string '6' (length=1)
      'id' => string '26249' (length=5)
```

Why does the following still return the same array without the `owner` element?

```
foreach ($result as $row)
{
    $row['owner'] = 1;
}
```

Comment: Because you don't change `$result`. You change only `$row` which contains a temporary copy of one item of `$result`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [passing the array by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php):

```
foreach ($result as &$row) {
    $row['owner'] = 1;
}
```

See also: [What's the `&` for, anyway?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058439/is-there-ever-a-need-to-use-ampersand-in-front-of-an-object)